# SimpleDateFormat, need textual Month

Tags: java, string, parsing, date, simpledateformat

I have this as a string `02/06/2012 1:25 PM EST`

I want to use SimpleDateFormat to return "Feb" from that data

Here is what I tried

```
SimpleDateFormat gottenDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
            String month = "";
            try {
                month = gottenDate.format(gottenDate.parse("02/06/2012 1:25 PM EST"));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Unfortunately `gottenDate.parse("02/06/2012 1:25 PM EST")` gets a parse exception when the SimpleDateFormat documents say it should work.

If I do `SimpleDateFormat gottenDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");` with two M's instead of 3, it returns "02" for me, as expected. The documents say that 3 or more M's should return a textual month. This doesn't happen, why? And yes, by now I could have made a string array of months and matched them to the numberic month SDF returned for me, but I am curious.

How do I make it work for me, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exception is expected in your case:

```
SimpleDateFormat gottenDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
gottenDate.parse("02/06/2012 1:25 PM EST");
```

"gottenDate" is set up to parse a string if it matches "MMM" pattern. The following should work:

```
SimpleDateFormat gottenDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
gottenDate.parse("Feb");
```

Hopefully you can see what's going on here.

Comment: I see now. Unfortunately the date I get is actually passed in to that method, and its format comes in as `"02/06/2012 1:25 PM EST"` , guess I will just make a corresponding array of months to tell it what `02` means

Comment: Not necessarily. You can make it as a two step process: 1) *parse* string using one SimpleDateFormat instance with a known pattern; 2) once you get a Date object - *format* it using another SimpleDateFormat instance like new SimpleDateFormat("MMM").

Answer (score 0):

You need a format to parse the date: `MM/dd/yyyy`, and once you have a Date object from this first date format, you need a second one: `MMM`, to format the date as you want.

Formatting with `MM` will give you the month on two digits, and parsing with `MMM` will expect an abbreviated textual month, and won't parse `02`.

Answer (score 0):

You need two separate `SimpeDateFormat` instances with corresponding format strings to parse source date and format it back into short month form. Your format instance can't parse full date because it expecting only month in specified string.

```
SimpleDateFormat monthDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
SimpleDateFormat gottenDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy h:mm a z");
String month = "";
try {
    month = monthDate .format(gottenDate.parse("02/06/2012 1:25 PM EST"));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Not sure about format of your source string, complex format strings are little tricky.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that will get MonthName to you:

```
public String getMonthName(String dtstr, String fmt) throws ParseException {
   SimpleDateFormat gottenDate = new SimpleDateFormat(fmt);
   SimpleDateFormat month = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
   Date dt = gottenDate.parse(dtstr);
   return month.format(dt);
}
```

Call it like this:

```
System.out.println(getMonthName("01/06/2012 1:25 PM EST"), "M/d/y");
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Feb
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, others were faster answering, but I think this will do what you want.

```
String date_str = "02/06/2012 1:25 PM EST";
SimpleDateFormat in_format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm aa zzz");
SimpleDateFormat out_format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
Date my_date = in_format.parse(date_str);
String out_str = out_format.format(my_date);
System.out.println(out_str); // Prints Feb
```

Dates and times can get complicated because of the way people in different record times. The best reference I've found for understanding all this is here:
http://www.odi.ch/prog/design/datetime.php

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide an alternative solution, since your jobs is to "extract" the month of a Date, I think [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) best fits the job.

```
// Construct a Date object
final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/y");
final Date originalDate = df.parse("02/06/2012 1:25 PM EST");

final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(originalDate); // set the calendar Date
// Extract the month
String month = c.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.SHORT, Locale.US);
System.out.println(month);
```